# iOS: black line on Launch Image from asset catalog

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, launchimage

I'm working on a iOS project where I'm using the assets catalog with a Launch Image. Everything seems to be correctly configured, the assets catalog doesn't show me any warnings about image size, but when I test the app, the Launch Image shows with a black line on the left:

[image: Launch Image]

My stack is:

- Xcode 7.1
- iOS deployment target: 8.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like your image is having transparent area as a part of png. Though the actual size could be as per the requirements. Do check the image for transparent area and then for actual size.

Comment: thanks man, never though about some transparency on the original image, problem solved ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check for the transparent area in image file to rectify this issue.
2. Replace the rectified launch image to the image assets.
3. Test the image on the relevant simulator or device.

I had same problem earlier and solved in the same manner.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, I've already solved with the comment by @piyush-mathur but as you give an actual answer I'm going to mark your answer as the correct one.